# Is there a way for a TextInput to behave like a button i.e. be able to be selected (onPress) or can the user enter the title of a button?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, tags

I am making a react native health app in which the user can select tags to describe certain symptoms they are facing. I am trying to let the user create their own tags, at the moment the user can enter tags but cannot select them. Is there a way to allow them to select text inputs?

Here is how I have allowed users to create text inputs

```
 addTextInput = (index) => {
    let textInput = this.state.textInput;
    textInput.push(
        <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.addValues(text, index)}
            editable={true}              
        />
    );

    this.setState({ textInput });
}
removeTextInput = () => {
    let textInput = this.state.textInput;
    let inputData = this.state.inputData;
    textInput.pop();
    inputData.pop();
    this.setState({ textInput, inputData });
}
```

and this is what my current tags look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5znWo.jpg

on the picture when the user presses the plus a new tag/TextInput is created, what I want is when the user presses it, it should be able to change color or the like.

here is the code for the plus button:

```
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexGrow: '1', flexWrap: 'wrap', width: Responsive.width(300) }}>
                            {this.state.textInput.map((value) => {
                                return value
                            })}
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                                this.addTextInput(this.state.textInput.length)
                            }
                            }>
                                <Image
                                    style={{ marginLeft: 8, width: 38, height: 38 }}
                                    source={require('../../../assets/plusButton.png')}
                                />
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            {/* <Button title='Get Values' onPress={() => this.getValues()} /> */}
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <View style={{ margin: 10, top: Responsive.height(75) }}>
                                <Button onPress={() => this.removeTextInput()}>Remove</Button>
                            </View>
                        </View>
```

Comment: Why not wrap the TextInput with TouchableOpacity component?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried wrapping it with TouchableOpacity but when I press the TextInput it only allows me to change the text or place the cursor. Is there a way to stop that and make it act like a button?

Comment: @JJK At the top of my head I think you can set `editable={false}` on the `TextInput` so the default behavior of focusing won't happen. You will probably have to add some styles to make it not look disabled though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, setting editable to false doesn't allow the user to enter text. Is there a way to allow the user to enter a input once and make the input non-editable?

Comment: You could create a state which is by default set to false and pass that to editable. Then you could set the state value to false inside onBlur or onEndEditing for example.